# Como colocar mais de um metodo Get, juntamente com o codigo sql para enviar as informações no bd ? Exemplo: Colocar email e senha

Tags: php, mysql, sql, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

**Usuario.php**

```
    #Conexao/categoria.php
    include_once 'conexao.php';

    class UsuarioDAO{
        public function Inserir(Usuario $usu){
            try{
                if (!empty($usu->getNome())){
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (nome) VALUES (:n)";

                    $sp_sql = Conexao::getInstance()->prepare($sql);

                    $sp_sql->bindValue(":n", $usu->getNome());

                    return $sp_sql->execute();
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }

            } catch (Exception $e){
                print $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
```

**usuarioObj.php**

```
<?php
    //Controller/categoriaObj.php
    include_once '..\Model\usuario.php';
    include_once '..\Conexao\usuario.php';

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];

    //instanciar o objeto
    $usu = new Usuario($id, $nome, $email, $senha);
    $usuDAO = new UsuarioDAO();

    //Chamar o método para mostrar a tabuada
    $usuDAO->Inserir($usu);
?>
```

Comment: você precisa ser mais claro, sua pergunta está muito vaga.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou tentar ajudar, imagino que "colocar mais um método Get" seja algo referente aos Gets dos atributos da classe Usuario. Como tem um getNome() e você precisa adicionar um e-mail, imagino que tenha um método getEmail() em sua classe Usuario e também um campo email em seu banco de dados (estou apenas supondo que seja essa sua dúvida).

Se eu tiver entendido corretamente, em seu código pode ser feito algo como abaixo:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (nome, email) VALUES (:n, :e)";

                $sp_sql = Conexao::getInstance()->prepare($sql);

                $sp_sql->bindValue(":n", $usu->getNome());
                $sp_sql->bindValue(":e", $usu->getEmail());
```

Perceba que para cada coluna no banco de dados, como está utilizando o bindValues, você deve criar um parâmetro para cada um.